How to turn Audio Output into Virtual Microphone?
I have an APp that converts Audio input from microphone to a specific Filter I am trying to  implement on the audio for a project.
It is needed to make the app interpret the audio from the app as a microphone and redirect between them. I am new on linux. Have searched a bit about pulseaudio.Have been able to play a bit with it, but not to the point of creating a virtual microphone.
If possible wonder if it can be done trough the terminal due the need of not using a lot of resources on the machine. Also would be good as to learn more about how audio works on linux machines. If any reader knows this or can redirect me to some source that would be able to do it appreciate it .
TL;dr: How to turn audio output from an app into a virtual microphone to be interpreted by another application.
If this is not the place feel free to Delete teh question. Appreciate it .
People said the previous question is equal to this one->
When Installing the software recommended there, got to a personal problem is the machine in which I am using linux as of now has a limit of 10gb unfortunately. Very peculiar machine lol. This is also a good way of getting the most out of linux in a way ig too. The terminal use appeared as a request due to this peculiar case ! Appreciate he answer provided. By Marcus Muller below

This question is similar to: Virtual Cable on Linux - How to import audio from a source ( app ) , for example, to a microhpne. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ChanganAuto this here clearly asks for a way to do it on the command line.


If possible wonder if it can be done trough the terminal due the need of not using a lot of resources on the machine.

whether or not you do it on the terminal has exactly zero influence on the computational needs of the audio redirection.
So, as illustrated in the answer to your previous question, qpwgraph does exactly that, no special tooling needed.
You can of course use the command line. First, you'd use pw-link --output to figure out which output ports you want, then  pw-link --input to figure out the input ports and then connect them using pw-link ${name of output port} ${name of input port}.
To reiterate that, this has absolutely no computational advantage over using qpwgraph. All that qwpgraph does is make it easier for you to figure out what to connect; under the hood, it calls the same functions as pw-link.

Have searched a bit about pulseaudio.

You're not using pulseaudio, but pipewire, as explained in the aforementioned answer.

Also would be good as to learn more about how audio works on linux machines.

You use a library to write samples to an output (as on basically every major operating system; your choice here is between the emulated lower-level libasound and libpipewire, or one of the many abstraction layer libraries, from libportaudio to libgstreamer).
There's a daemon that routes the output to the devices or programs it should go. (and that's also basically what happens on any other operating system; some OSes might have that daemon as service on the OS kernel side of things, but I think the large ones really just schedule a daemon process to handle the audio stream)

Apprecaite the Answer Again !! My Machine simply got a limited storage as of now. 10 gb max and when installing thepwgraph it said it would end up with 3.6 gb. It is a peculiar machine I have here, that is why I asked for the terminal usage. Appreciate the Answer !! Excellent answer. Will check this with additional attention!

really, try installing it; you can afterwards remove it completely again. You accepted my previous answer without trying – and without even telling us you didn't try. Obviously, that's a bad start – we can't know what does and doesn't work for you. And spending a solid amount of time writing an answer just for you to then not trying it – that's pretty disappointing for an answerer.

I am sorry, My Computer is very bad.as of now. Agree that the answer wasnt good enough Have installed pwgraph right now but it is a lot heavy for my machine. I need to see what should really be done. And I am slow on learning too
